# how to store trained weights and biases in model A for use in model B in tensorflow

Tags: tensorflow

Suppose I have construct a neural network A with a dictionary of weights and biases variable, and I have get specific values for weights and biases after training in neural network A. And I want to use these specific value to replace the `tf.Variable` in neural network B. How could I achieve this purpose? I have tried `tf.train.Saver()`, however, I don't know how to restore the weights and biases in another network B (in another file). I have also tried storing them using `pickle.dump`, however, I met with another problem, i.e. when restoring `weights` and `biases` using `pickle.load`, it said `dictionary` type is not hashable. Could anyone help me solve this problem?

Answer (score 1):

The [`tf.train.Saver`](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.7/api_docs/python/state_ops.html#Saver) class should help with this, although you might need to use some of the optional arguments to get it to work.

Let's say your model A looks like this, and you've trained it and saved it to a file called `"/tmp/model_a_ckpt"`:

```
weights_a = tf.Variable(..., name="weights_a")
biases_a = tf.Variable(..., name="biases_a")
# ...

saver_a = tf.train.Saver()
# ...
saver_a.save(sess, "/tmp/model_a_ckpt")
```

...and then let's say your model B looks like this:

```
weights_b = tf.Variable(..., name="weights_b")
biases_b = tf.Variable(..., name="biases_b")
```

To load the checkpoint into model B you have to create a saver that *maps* the names of variables in the checkpoint (i.e. `"weights_a"` and `"biases_a"` because they default to the `name` property of the corresponding `tf.Variable` objects in model A) to the variables in model B:

```
saver_b = tf.train.Saver({"weights_a": weights_b, "biases_a": biases_b})
# ...
saver_b.restore(sess, "/tmp/model_a_ckpt")
```

After running `saver_b.restore()`, your variables in model B will have the values trained in model A.

Comment: How can I restore the `weights_a`  when it is a dictionary type, i.e. a combination of several weight variables named by `w_a1`, `w_a2`? Do I need to reconstruct the dictionary by myself?

Comment: Here I got my question answered about how to work with a dictionary of weights: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43983528/how-do-i-store-and-rebuild-and-dictionary-of-weights-in-tensorflow