# How do I store and rebuild and dictionary of weights in tensorflow

Tags: python, dictionary, tensorflow

When training I store my weights in a dictionary of tensorflow-variables. I pass that dictionary of weights to a 'model'-function together with some data to get my desired output.
After training, I would like to store that dictionary in a file in such a way that I can recreate it. That way I can apply the learned weights by simply passing the dictionary of weights together with the new data to the same model function.
According to [the documentation](https://www.tensorflow.org/programmers_guide/variables#choosing_which_variables_to_save_and_restore), simply passing the dictionary of weights to a saver should save those weights under the correct names. Then I should be able to create the same dictionary in the application function and then restore the saved values. However if I do this, I get an 'values are uninitialized'-error. Can anyone help me find what I am doing wrong?

Minimal self-contained code example and corresponding error:

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np

# first train a linear model on random vectors of length 5 and store the trained parameters.
# Then load those parameters and try to apply them to a new vector.
def run():
    train_model()
    apply_model()

def train_model():    
    # create random training data: 100 vectors of length 5 for both input and output.
    train_data  = np.random.random((100,5))
    train_labels = np.random.random((100,5))

    train_data_node = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=(5), name="train_data_node")
    train_labels_node = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=(5), name="train_labels_node")

    weights = defineWeights()

    prediction = model(train_data_node, weights)
    loss = tf.norm(prediction - train_labels_node)
    train_op = tf.train.AdagradOptimizer(learning_rate=1).minimize(loss)

    saver = tf.train.Saver(weights)

    sess = tf.Session()
    sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
    # train for 50 epochs on all 100 training examples, with a batchsize of 1.
    for _ in range(50):
        for i in range(100):
            batch_data = train_data[i,:]
            batch_labels = train_labels[i,:]

            feed_dict = {train_data_node: batch_data, train_labels_node: batch_labels}
            sess.run([train_op, loss, weights], feed_dict=feed_dict)
        saver.save(sess, '/results/weights')

def apply_model():
    sess = tf.Session()

    weights = defineWeights()

    new_saver = tf.train.import_meta_graph('/results/weights.meta')
    new_saver.restore(sess, tf.train.latest_checkpoint('/results'))

    print(model(np.random.random(5).astype(np.float32), weights).eval(session=sess))


def model(data, weights):
    # multiply the matrix weights['a'] with the vector data
    l1 = tf.matmul(tf.expand_dims(data,0), weights['a'])
    l1 = l1 + weights['b']
    return l1

def defineWeights():
    weights = {
        'a': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([5, 5],
                                                        stddev=0.01, 
                                                        dtype =  tf.float32),
                                                        name = 'a'),
        'b': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([5]), name = 'b'),
        }
    return weights
```

Calling the 'run()' function in the code above gives the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/myFolder/example.py", line 8, in run
    apply_model()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/myFolder/example.py", line 50, in apply_model
    print(model(np.random.random(5).astype(np.float32), weights).eval(session=sess))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py", line 569, in eval
    return _eval_using_default_session(self, feed_dict, self.graph, session)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py", line 3741, in _eval_using_default_session
    return session.run(tensors, feed_dict)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 786, in run
    run_metadata_ptr)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 994, in _run
    feed_dict_string, options, run_metadata)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 1044, in _do_run
    target_list, options, run_metadata)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 1064, in _do_call
    raise type(e)(node_def, op, message)
tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.FailedPreconditionError: Attempting to use uninitialized value a_1
     [[Node: a_1/read = Identity[T=DT_FLOAT, _class=["loc:@a_1"], _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/gpu:0"](a_1)]]
     [[Node: add_2/_5 = _Recv[client_terminated=false, recv_device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/cpu:0", send_device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/gpu:0", send_device_incarnation=1, tensor_name="edge_7_add_2", tensor_type=DT_FLOAT, _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/cpu:0"]()]]

Caused by op u'a_1/read', defined at:
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/myFolder/example.py", line 8, in run
    apply_model()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/myFolder/example.py", line 45, in apply_model
    weights = defineWeights()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/myFolder/example.py", line 63, in defineWeights
    name = 'a'),
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/variables.py", line 197, in __init__
    expected_shape=expected_shape)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/variables.py", line 316, in _init_from_args
    self._snapshot = array_ops.identity(self._variable, name="read")
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/gen_array_ops.py", line 1338, in identity
    result = _op_def_lib.apply_op("Identity", input=input, name=name)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/op_def_library.py", line 768, in apply_op
    op_def=op_def)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py", line 2336, in create_op
    original_op=self._default_original_op, op_def=op_def)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py", line 1228, in __init__
    self._traceback = _extract_stack()

FailedPreconditionError (see above for traceback): Attempting to use uninitialized value a_1
     [[Node: a_1/read = Identity[T=DT_FLOAT, _class=["loc:@a_1"], _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/gpu:0"](a_1)]]
     [[Node: add_2/_5 = _Recv[client_terminated=false, recv_device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/cpu:0", send_device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/gpu:0", send_device_incarnation=1, tensor_name="edge_7_add_2", tensor_type=DT_FLOAT, _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/cpu:0"]()]]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I edited your code to make it work - One possible way !  Check it.

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np

# first train a linear model on random vectors of length 5 and store the trained parameters.
# Then load those parameters and try to apply them to a new vector.
def run():
    train_model()
    apply_model()

def train_model():
     # create random training data: 100 vectors of length 5 for both input and output.
     train_data  = np.random.random((100,5))
     train_labels = np.random.random((100,5))

     train_data_node = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=(5), name="train_data_node")
     train_labels_node = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=(5), name="train_labels_node")

     weights = defineWeights()

     prediction = model(train_data_node, weights)
     prediction = tf.identity(prediction, name="prediction")

     loss = tf.norm(prediction - train_labels_node)
     train_op = tf.train.AdagradOptimizer(learning_rate=1).minimize(loss)

     saver = tf.train.Saver()

     sess = tf.Session()
     sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
     # train for 50 epochs on all 100 training examples, with a batchsize of 1.
     for _ in range(50):
        for i in range(100):
            batch_data = train_data[i,:]
            batch_labels = train_labels[i,:]

            feed_dict = {train_data_node: batch_data, train_labels_node: batch_labels}
            sess.run([train_op, loss, weights], feed_dict=feed_dict)
            saver.save(sess, 'results/model')
     print("Trained Weights")
     print(sess.run(weights))

def apply_model():
    sess = tf.Session()

    new_saver = tf.train.import_meta_graph('results/model.meta')
    new_saver.restore(sess, tf.train.latest_checkpoint('results'))


    print("Loaded Weights")
    print(sess.run(['a:0','b:0']))

    prediction = tf.get_default_graph().get_tensor_by_name("prediction:0")
    train_data_node = tf.get_default_graph().get_tensor_by_name("train_data_node:0")

    test_data = np.random.random(5).astype(np.float32)
    pred = sess.run([prediction],feed_dict={train_data_node:test_data})
    print("Prediction")
    print(pred)


def model(data, weights):
    # multiply the matrix weights['a'] with the vector data
    l1 = tf.matmul(tf.expand_dims(data,0), weights['a'])
    l1 = l1 + weights['b']
    return l1

def defineWeights():
    weights = {
       'a': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([5, 5],
                                                    stddev=0.01, 
                                                    dtype =  tf.float32),
                                                    name = 'a'),
       'b': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([5]), name = 'b'),
    }
return weights

def main(_):
    run()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    tf.app.run(main=main)
```

Output:

```
Trained Weights
{'a': array([[ 0.01243415, -0.42879951,  0.0174435 , -0.24622701,  0.35309449],
   [ 0.03154161, -0.08194152,  0.09223857, -0.15719411, -0.06323836],
   [-0.03263358,  0.05096304,  0.1769278 , -0.17564282,  0.04325204],
   [-0.17412457, -0.00338688,  0.08468977, -0.06877152, -0.02180972],
   [ 0.25160244, -0.19224152,  0.14535131, -0.20594895, -0.03813718]], dtype=float32), 'b': array([ 0.33825615,  0.79861975,  0.30609566,  0.91897982,  0.20577262], dtype=float32)}
I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:975] Creating TensorFlow device (/gpu:0) -> (device: 0, name: GeForce GTX 1060 6GB, pci bus id: 0000:01:00.0)
Loaded Weights
[array([[ 0.01243415, -0.42879951,  0.0174435 , -0.24622701,  0.35309449],
   [ 0.03154161, -0.08194152,  0.09223857, -0.15719411, -0.06323836],
   [-0.03263358,  0.05096304,  0.1769278 , -0.17564282,  0.04325204],
   [-0.17412457, -0.00338688,  0.08468977, -0.06877152, -0.02180972],
   [ 0.25160244, -0.19224152,  0.14535131, -0.20594895, -0.03813718]], dtype=float32), array([ 0.33825615,  0.79861975,  0.30609566,  0.91897982,  0.20577262], dtype=float32)]
Prediction
[array([[ 0.3465074 ,  0.42139536,  0.71310139,  0.30854774,  0.32671657]], dtype=float32)]
```

Explanation:

1. Name the tensors which you want to access after restoring.
2. Restore the graph and restore variables that you named - shown in apply_model()
3. Feed the new test_data into placeholder using feed_dict

Issues:

1. I tried to use *sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())* but it is re-initializing variables to new random values. (Using TF 1.0)

I hope this helps !

Comment: Thanks, this helps a lot! The only question I have left is regarding tensorflow variable naming. As you use in the code: if you name a variable 'a', tensorflow will name that variable 'a:0' to uniquify it. Do you know if we can rely on tensorflow always doing exactly this? Because if tensorflow suddenly decided to add ':1' to variable names, this code sample would break.