# how to restore a subset of the variables used by a model in tensorflow

Tags: tensorflow, restore

I have 2 file, learn.py to save the model, learn_2.py to restore the model(here is the tf.variable a) and initialize the new tf.variable b, but something going wrong, here is the wrong:

```
tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.NotFoundError: Key scope/bb not found in checkpoint
```

learn.py

```
import tensorflow as tf

with tf.variable_scope("scope"):
    a = tf.get_variable("aa", shape=[2,4])

sess = tf.Session()
#sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
sess.run(tf.initialize_variables([a]))
saver = tf.train.Saver()
save_path = saver.save(sess, "./tmp/model.ckpt")
print "---"
print sess.run(a)
```

learn_2.py

```
import tensorflow as tf

with tf.variable_scope("scope"):
    a = tf.get_variable("aa", shape=[2,4])
    b = tf.get_variable("bb", shape=[2,4])
sess = tf.Session()
#sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
#sess.run(tf.initialize_variables([b]))
saver = tf.train.Saver()
save_path = saver.restore(sess, "./tmp/model.ckpt")
sess.run(tf.initialize_variables([b]))
print "---"
print sess.run(a)
print sess.run(b)
```

Comment: Which line gives this error ? Does it work if you load the graph before creating and initializinf vvariable b ? If so, is it a problem for you to do things in that order ?

Comment: @gdelab in the line 10(save_path = saver.restore(sess, "./tmp/model.ckpt")), no mater create the graph first or restore old model first, it always have the problem

Comment: Have a look at this example (shows saving + restoring variables) : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43983528/how-do-i-store-and-rebuild-and-dictionary-of-weights-in-tensorflow/43988865#43988865

Comment: Let me know if you have any more queries.

Comment: @hars yeah, you are right, i know how to save and restore variables, it's work. But, when i write file1 to save the model and file2 to load the model, it doesn't work, just like i written above. Maybe you can just copy the code above and have a try, thanks a lot

Comment: @hars exactly, i want to do this [link](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.11/how_tos/variables/index.html#choosing-which-variables-to-save-and-restore), eg: I have trained a neural net with 5 layers, and I now want to train a new model with 6 layers, so restoring the parameters from the 5 layers of the previously trained model into the first 5 layers of the new model. But, when I try to restore the variables from the old model and init the last layer, something going wrong. So I do some test like this, it doesn't work either.

Comment: @colourful_tree, See my answer. Run it and let me know if it works for you as well.

Answer (score 0):

Do this in second script learn2.py. Works for me !

```
import tensorflow as tf

with tf.variable_scope("scope"):
    a = tf.get_variable("aa", shape=[2,4])
    sess = tf.Session()
    saver = tf.train.Saver()
    save_path = saver.restore(sess, "/tmp/model.ckpt")
    b = tf.get_variable("bb", shape=[2,4])
    sess.run(tf.initialize_variables([b]))
    print "---"
    print sess.run(a)
    print sess.run(b)
```

Output of script 1 (same as learn.py)

```
---
[[ 0.21811056  0.75089216  0.43180299 -0.36542225]
 [-0.11786985 -0.26542974  0.68785524 -0.57991886]]
```

Output of script 2 (as above)

```
---
[[ 0.21811056  0.75089216  0.43180299 -0.36542225]
 [-0.11786985 -0.26542974  0.68785524 -0.57991886]]
[[-0.62411451 -0.32599163  0.72495079 -0.09547448]
 [-0.59518242  0.51209545 -0.68833208 -0.03813028]]
```

Explanation:

You added variables "a" and "b" to graph in second script. When you try to restore, it will search for all variables in the present graph ("a" & "b"). My solution is

1. Build the graph same as which you want to restore first.
2. Restore the graph - all variables
3. Add nodes/layers to graph and initialize only newly added variables.

I hope this helps.

Comment: Yeah, it's work now! Thanks a lot for you Explanation.

Comment: @colourful_tree, Good to hear that. please accept/vote the answer so that question will get closed.